# MySQL Use index with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with 500M+ rows, and I want to speed up searches. The Data is formatted as such:

```
Timestamp           |  Open  |  High  |  Low  |  Close  | Volume | Ticker
2016-12-12 14:31:00 |  23.35 | 23.35  | 23.35 |  23.35  | 100    | RNG
2016-12-12 14:32:00 |  23.35 | 23.35  | 23.35 |  23.35  | 0      | RNG
2016-12-12 14:33:00 |  23.35 | 23.35  | 23.35 |  23.35  | 0      | RNG
2016-12-12 14:34:00 |  23.4  | 23.4   | 23.4  |  23.4   | 250    | RNG

...

2018-11-09 20:54:00 | 42.785 | 42.785 | 42.78  | 42.785 | 1300.0 | EWW
2018-11-09 20:55:00 | 42.785 | 42.805 | 42.785 | 42.805 | 1500.0 | EWW
2018-11-09 20:56:00 | 42.805 | 42.805 | 42.755 | 42.755 | 2500.0 | EWW
2018-11-09 20:57:00 | 42.755 | 42.755 | 42.755 | 42.755 | 1600.0 | EWW
2018-11-09 20:58:00 | 42.725 | 42.725 | 42.715 | 42.725 | 7500.0 | EWW
```

where the data for each ticker is located next to each other in ascending chronological order

I want to search on the basis of the ticker, something like

`SELECT * FROM minutely WHERE ticker="AAPL"`

but considering the size of the table this is rather slow. I considered using indexes but as the ticker column contains duplicate values this is not possible.

Currently if I try the command `ALTER TABLE minutely ADD primary key (ticker);` I get `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'RNG' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Post Script:

I apologize if this is not the correct exchange for this sort of question; if not, please suggest a better location.

Comment: Does `Ticker` column have a (pretty) fixed number of values?

Comment: There are 3000 different tickers, each with a maximum length of 6 characters, and each with 194,738 entries

Comment: *"I considered using indexes but as the ticker column contains duplicate values this is not possible."* You can make non unique indexes in MySQL.which in thoery can help if the MySQL optimizer is using that index when you query it.

Comment: interesting, could you give me an `ALTER TABLE` example command to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead  of a primary key  (that is unique by definition) 
You should simply create an index

```
create index my_idx on minutely  ( ticker) ;
```

a normal index (not unique)  allowe  duplicated  value

Comment: maybe adding `LOCK=NONE ALGORITHM=INPLACE` to use/force InnoDB's online DDL it's a (pretty) big table..

Comment: @BWP  you should also upvote  Raymond Nijland somewhere for valid suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your data would appear to have a natural primary key, with two components.  So try this:

```
ALTER TABLE minutely ADD primary key (ticker, timestamp);
```

Your query should be faster with this as a primary key than building a separate index.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea is to use LIMIT at your query

```
SELECT * FROM minutely WHERE ticker="AAPL" LIMIT 256;
```

This provide end of the **SELECT** command without all table checking.
256 is a example of maximum of expected numbers of row you can get.

If you don't know the LIMIT consider the check it first, and do it after possibility of expected higer value of row with the same **ticker**.

Comment: Bad idea, using `LIMIT` clause without `ORDER BY` clause is **meaningless**  and **non-deterministic** because SQL resultsets are by definition (SQL standards) **orderless** without `ORDER BY` clause